# Trying to hide base class member during serialization with Json.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, json.net

I have two classes, where the concrete class `Model<T>` hides the base class' `Items` property.

```
class Model
{
    List<ListItem> Items {get;set;}
}

class Model<T> : Model
{
    new List<ListItem<T>> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Upon serializing an instance of `Model<T>` with Json.NET I get the error:

> `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException`: A member with the name '`Items`' already exists on '`Model<T>`'. Use the `JsonPropertyAttribute` to specify another name.

I understand why I'm receiving this error, however, I don't want to change the property name on the concrete class; I want to be able to tell the serializer to ignore the base class property.

I tried using the `ShouldSerialize{PropertyName}()` convention that `XmlSerializer` supports, and [Json.NET claims to support too](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/04/16/json-net-3-5-release-7-bson-binary-json-part-deux.aspx), however this doesn't seem to work for my scenario.

Comment: Is `Model<T>` the only type that will ever be serialized or is it possible that you would want to serialize a `Model` object as well?

Comment: @M.Babcock I should have clarified, `Model` can be serialized too... otherwise it would have been straightforward to mark `Model.Items` with `[JsonIgnore]`

Comment: Can you make the `Items` in the base class virtual and use `override` instead of hiding with `new`? I know it isn't really what you're asking for, but if you have control over both types; why not do it the "right" way?

Comment: @M.Babcock the types are different, so overriding won't work

Comment: Fair enough (I overlooked that). Any chance `ListItem` and `ListItem<T>` inherit a common interface or share a common base?

Comment: @M.Babcock yes, they do implement a common interface actually.  however, if you're suggesting that i change the property type to `List<IListItem>`, that will likely cause some other issues.

Comment: Which version of Json.NET? I'm unable to reproduce the problem with 4.0.8.

Comment: i think you're right, seems the issue may have been fixed in 4.0.6: http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/80975

Comment: Is upgrading an option? If not you could try using `JsonPropertyAttribute` on `Items` AND using `ShouldSerializeItems()` on the `Model` class.

Comment: @rsbarro upgrading is an option, though in my initial testing it seems that their "fix" was to avoid serializing the property all together!

Comment: In 4.0.8, when I serialize Model<T> it serializes the Items property on Model<T> and ignore the Items property on the base class. Wasn't that what you wanted? =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [rsbarro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304096/trying-to-hide-base-class-member-during-serialization-with-json-net#comment11736578_9304096) for pointing out that this was fixed in a later version of Json.NET (v4.0.6.0).  I've upgraded and confirmed that the correct property is now serialized.