# How to serialize a c# object to Json with namespace. If it is possible some how

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Base class contains a property that is hide by a new property in sub class but of different type. when deserializing, i am facing issue. I cann't change the name of the property in c# or json but can add namespace if possible.

```
namespace xyz
{
    public class A
    {
        public ICollection<xyz.OrganizationAttribute> OrganizationAttributes { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace pqr
{
    public class AX : A
    {
        public new ICollection<pqr.OrganizationAttribute> OrganizationAttributes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
    JsonConvert.SerializeObject( axObject, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead,
        DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore
    } );

    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>( "axjsonString", new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead
    } );
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: How do you deserialize? Usually if you cast the resulting object to AX C# will automatically creates the property of the descendant type. Post your deserialization mechanism here

Comment: @Emad I am deserializing AX json to A object using NewtonSoft with ReadAHead setting. var a = result.Documents?.Select( x => x.ToObject<A>( new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.ReadAhead
            } ) );

Comment: 1) Can you modify the base class `A` in any way?  2) Do you both the `xyz.OrganizationAttribute` and `pqr.OrganizationAttribute` collections to appear in the file, or just the derived collection?  3) If your type `AX` ignores the `xyz` collection, that would seem to violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56860/what-is-the-liskov-substitution-principle).  Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: Also, have you tested this?  According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304096/trying-to-hide-base-class-member-during-serialization-with-json-net/9315113#9315113) it should just work as of Json.NET v4.0.6.0.

Comment: @dbc 1) No, 2) No, I don't have xyz.OrganizationAttribute in json or anywhere. but unfortunately, It is a property in class A. 3) I want to rename pqr.OrganizationAttribute property but can't for now.

Comment: Actually, this seems to work perfectly already. See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TR4sfS.  Can you explain what the problem is?

Comment: @IrshadAli - I don't understand what you are doing.  Are you serializing an object of type `AX`, then deserializing as type `A` -- I.e. trying to use Json.NET to map an instance of the derived type to an instance of the base type?

Comment: @dbc, thank you for your dotnetfiddle link, it helped me directing in a right direction. for your second comment, yes. The error was due to presence of "$id": 1 additional property created to find circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you said in the comments there is no way to have 'pqr.OrganizationAttribute' in class A that's not related to JSon or deserialization, that's just how OOP works. Hiding a method or field in a class propagates down in inheritance hierarchy therefore when talking about `A` you can't talk about fields that it's children like `AX` has re-defined.

You can read more about this [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))

**Edit**

All right I got what you want to do now. Use this:

```
public static A FromJson(string input) 
{
    var json = JToken.Parse(input);
    json["OrganizationAttribute"].Remove();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, A object cannot have 'pqr.OrganizaitonAttribute'. I just want to ignore OrganizationAttributes when i deserialize AX json to A object. I cannot modify class A.

Comment: @IrshadAli see the edit. What you want is to manipulate the JSon. For the record I have to say that it's not a good idea to use JSon created from one model to deserialize into another model.